# Modify "Edit this Task" Outlook button for SharePoint 2010 workflow task custom content type

Tags: workflow, infopath, content-type

I have created a custom content type based off of workflow task content type by following along with this article http://fmuntean.wordpress.com/2009/11/27/infopath-task-forms-made-easy-part-2/

Everything works as expected when editing the task directly from the "Tasks" list. When the default task email is sent out, there is a button at the top labeled "Edit this Task" when viewing the message in Outlook 2007. This button does not use the modified "WrkTaskIP.aspx" page that I created, but instead uses the standard _layouts/FormServer.aspx URL.

This is causing two problems in our current configuration:

1. Custom WrkTaskIP form I've modified contains two XmlFormView controls that display the current steps InfoPath form and also a "Print" version of the original InfoPath form. Since this is not using my custom page, only the current steps task form is displayed.
2. The form data never makes it back to the workflow since I am using the methods described in the above article to serialize and de-serialize my InfoPath form data to and from the workflow.

Is there any way to override the URL used by the "Edit this Task" button to point to my WrkTaskIP.aspx page instead of the standard _layouts/FormServer.aspx?